# React-Native: 'List of devices attached' not showing any device. Also, 'Could not get BatchedBridged' issue

Tags: android, facebook, reactjs, react-native

### Description

Hi, I'm **new to the react-native** platform. I followed all the steps given here: [react-native getting-started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content), to setup my development environment.

#### Details

- React Native version: 0.42
- Platform I want to work for: Android
- Operating System: Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 64-bit)
- Phone: OnePlus 2 - AndroidVersion 6.0.1 - Marshmallow

I followed these steps: [running-on-device](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html), to run the app on my phone connected to my laptop via USB cable. I've enabled debugging over USB and inserted device id in udev rules with the process mentioned.

Now when I run `$ adb devices`
It lists no android device attached. Here's how it looks:

[image]

Also, when I run `$ react-native run-android`
then my phone shows these messages:

[image]

[image]

Being totally new to the platform, I really need help. Can someone please explain what could be wrong here. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't look like a problem with `react-native` but with your phone setup. I suggest looking into issues with `adb` rather than `react-native`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (on windows) I needed to install the drivers for the device for developer tools to work.

The following links were helpful:

[react-native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device)

[ADB Device Not Found Error on Windows](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/solved-adb-device-not-found-error-on-windows/)

[ADB, Samsung_Android and Win x64 - Solved](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2311487)

Answer (score 1):

Just update your phone driver through device manager and then it will appear when you run `adb devices`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run react-native start. Then run adb devices. If no device appears, try to reinstall adb, or use an emulator.

I use emulator for development, and it is pretty good with hot reloading.

Answer (score 0):

From React-native Doc [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)
Many React Native modules haven't been tested on Marshmallow and might break. Please thoroughly test the app if you target API level 23 and file a bug report if you find that something is broke.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue today and finally device listed in adb by restarting adb server

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue occured due to usb debugging not enabled in your phone. Once enabled  try below comment.

- sudo adb kill-server
- sudo adb start-server
- adb devices

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have MIDI mode selected when phone's connected through cable(not file transfer or any other).